# Profile Pic on right side bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not an UI Developer but this time need to play in css. Writing a form for User Profile. I'm almost done with it but a little issue is remaining. 
Issues

- Profile pic isn't coming on right side properly.
- so, first field (Organization Name) is not appearing correct

I have been playing in bootstrap since last two hours to fix this issue.
I changed many classes tried to add remove divs for that profile image. but no success.

Here it was the my last try:

```
.profile-pic{
    float:right;
    margin-right:50px;
    height:160px;
    width:140px;
}
```

But that did not work too.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddexocuq/)

Comment: can you point your problem with fiddle or image

Comment: @Amitsingh - Had forgot to add the Jsfiddle link. Now It's been added. Sorry about it.

Comment: your `css` is not perfect for figuring out the problem

Comment: I think in your case `margin` is affecting the profile pic to get on the right side

Comment: @Amitsingh - Just have a look at the last few lines. I am trying to update it through external resources.

Comment: @Amitsingh - Great, That worked a little, also why there is some extra space appearing after first `Text Field` ?

Comment: you are styling the `div` which has already got the `col-xs-4` class and which height is already mentioned in `bootstrap`. in this case you remove the `margin` and add `padding:0;` than you will see the image is in the right side

Comment: @Amitsingh - Thanks! You can answer that. also it had one more issue:
`.control-group:after` had css `display: table;` . After removing it seems working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

**CSS**

```
.profile-pic{
    float : right;
    height : 160px;
    width : 140px;
    padding : 0;
}
```